# Where is the Icon Tray (notification area) registry stored?

Tags: windows-registry, icons, notification-area

I'm in need to know where the position and order of the Icons from the System Tray are stored. (notification area)

I'm talking about these ones:

[image]

I've been trying to go through some reg files and my own guess is that it's somewhere here:

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\MUICache"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRU"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\LastVisitedPidlMRULegacy"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSaveMRU"
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist"
```

Comment: I don't believe this information is stored in the registry at all but only in memory and not user accessible

Comment: I've read it's not possible too, but I've seen some registries showing this, not sure about IconCache,

Comment: See answer by Dale Mahalko....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/677c0753-92ef-46ba-b239-437c3c6a38aa/where-are-the-system-tray-customizations-stored?forum=w7itproinstall

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever figured this out in the end, but I found the following key contains a list of apps that use the system tray:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings
```

And within some of those app keys, there is a DWORD called 'IsPromoted'.  If the value of this key is 1, the tray icon is visible always, and 0 means it is hidden.

If you change the value of IsPromoted, it has an immediate effect, as in you don't need to restart Explorer.exe.

I have tested this in Windows 11.

One thing of note is that the name of the key for each app is not consistent on each computer, for example the key for OneDrive.exe on one I checked is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings\5434357290411014857

But on another, the same app is listed under a different key name:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings\5889842883606957982

This also occurs between different users on the same device.

So, Windows appears to generate a unique app id when naming the keys, per user/system.  Therefore, the solution here would be to create a PowerShell script with a foreach loop to search through each key within 'NotifyIconSettings' to find the specific executables you are looking to promote, and when found, edit the IsPromoted DWORD with a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Powershell script that I've created for Windows 11 :)

```
#Title: Unhide systemtray icon by name.exe
#Version: 1.0

# List of executable paths to search for
$executablePaths = @(
    "*onedrive.exe*",
    "*clickpaste.exe*"
)

# Register path to 
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings"

# Get all subkeys under the registry path
$subKeys = Get-ChildItem -Path $registryPath

# Iterate through each subkey
foreach ($subKey in $subKeys) {
    # Get the ExecutablePath value
    $executablePath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$($subKey.PSPath)").ExecutablePath

    # Check if any of the specified executable paths match
    foreach ($path in $executablePaths) {
        if ($executablePath -like $path) {
            # Add or overwrite the IsPromoted DWORD value with decimal value 1
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "$($subKey.PSPath)" -Name "IsPromoted" -Value 1 -Type DWORD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            break
        }
    }
}
```