# Customize Windows to show "toast" notifications in different spots or filter them

Tags: windows-10, notifications, notification-area

I'm wondering if there's a way to customize windows-10 notifications. I've looked around for modifying the toast location and found:

[Where is the Icon Tray (notification area) registry stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1332399/where-is-the-icon-tray-notification-area-registry-stored)

Bonus points if I can change the look/feel of them. I'm okay with third party apps. Basically I want to be able to see messages from slack in the center of the screen when slack isn't visible, not in the periphery.

Edit: By filter I mean more than what's available in the Window's notification options. Perhaps I want notifications with the text "Warning" or "Error" to show but not others. Some applications provide a finer notification granularity than others, I'm hoping for a solution that would provide this capability in an application agnostic fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the BurntToast module. This module lets you create custom toast notifications on Windows 10

https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast

Adaptive and interactive toast notifications let you create flexible notifications with text, images, and buttons/inputs. The following Microsoft doc talking about this:

Toast content

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts

Also, I find out a Toast Notifications Desktop Application on Stack Overflow, it’s worthwhile to consult.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609521/windows-10-toast-notifications-desktop-application

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote your answer but don't have sufficient rep yet. I didn't manage to see a way to place the notifications in the center of the screen. I'm assuming this isn't possible without hacking about?